En C#, ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre sizeof y Marshal.SizeOf?
En C#, ¿Qué diferencia a sizeof de Marshal.SizeOf?

sizeof es un operador, que solo se admite en contextos de código no seguro, marcado como unsafe.
Devuelve el número de bytes ocupados por una variable de un tipo determinado. El argumento del operador sizeof debe ser el nombre de un tipo administrado o un parámetro de tipo que está restringido para ser un tipo no administrado.
Cuando hablamos de un tipo restringido para ser no administrado, nos referimos a algo como esto:
unsafe void SomeMethod<T>() where T : unmanaged
{
    // El tipo T está restringido para ser no administrado, entonces es admitido
    // para el operador sizeof.
    int size = sizeof(T);    
}

sizeof no admite tipos de referencia y, es más eficiente que Marshal.SizeOf<T> porque se evalúa en tiempo de compilación. Además, solo funciona con tipos de valor (structs, enums) que pueden ser copiados directamente en memoria sin transformación.
No obstante, la siguiente tabla muestra aquellas expresiones de sizeof que no requieren de un contexto inseguro (unsafe):


Marshal.SizeOf es un método estático de la clase Marshal, que devuelve el tamaño no administrado de un objeto, en bytes.
A diferencia de sizeof que se evalúa durante la compilación, Marshal.SizeOf es evaluado en tiempo de ejecución, lo que lo hace algo más lento, pero es más flexible, pues admite tanto tipos de referencia como tipos de valor y, por ende, puede calcular el tamaño de tipos de datos más complejos:
class MyClass {}
struct MyStruct {}

// Esto es válido.
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);

// Esto es válido.
MyStruct obj = new MyStruct();
int size = Marshal.SizeOf(obj);

El espacio de nombres para la clase Marshal es System.Runtime.InteropServices.
Como nota, puedes emplear Marshal.Sizeof para determinar la cantidad de memoria no administrada que se va a asignar mediante los métodos AllocHGlobal y AllocCoTaskMem.

Si lo deseas, puedes poner la tabla como texto, en formato markdown. Para resumir, las excepciones son los tipos primitivos numéricos de C# ya que siempre tendrán el mismo tamaño.

@Mateo Agradezco enormemente tu sugerencia, aunque la verdad, de momento quisiera dejar la publicación intacta. A lo mejor más adelante me animo y aplico el cambio que propones. Un saludo.
